# Changing file locations when changing from using computer storage to cloud storage

Tags: java, windows, ubuntu, jar

I'm having a problem when downloading my code off google drive in order to work on it. I usually work an ubuntu system, meaning that my jar folders are stored internally. However, I now want to work on a windows desktop, so I transferred my files via google drive, the problem being that the code still expects the jar folders to be in the ubuntu directory, which is impossible. How do I change the directories?

```
G:\My Drive\myusername:)\Login CSV\IA\nbproject\jfx-impl.xml:1234: Warning: Could not find resource file "C:\home\myusername:)\Downloads\JavaFXMLDatabaseConnector.jar" to copy.
```

That's the error message received, and this is the code that it references:

```
 <copy todir="${dist.dir}${file.separator}lib" flatten="true" preservelastmodified="true" overwrite="true">
```